# send_mail (smtp) from docker-compose (django + nginx + gunicorn)

Tags: django, docker-compose, smtp

I am trying to send email via Django. The mail should be sent to the user who would register to our system using Gmail.

I am also using docker-compse django, nginx, gunicorn and postgres.

This is my email configurations inside the django.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_HOST_USER = get_secret("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = get_secret("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

and docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: ./dj-psych
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static/
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/media/
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13.0
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/static
    ports:
      - server-port:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream config {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://config;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/app/media/;
    }
}
```

I think the smtp server port (586) should be open in docker.

So I tried binding port web and nginx. But I can't.

how can i do it??

I tried.

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
email = EmailMessage('subject', 'body', to=['email@gmail.com'])
email.send()
```

This is error message

```
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

---

The assumption I made is this:

1. The port (8000->80) entering Nginx from Django is responsible for both internal server port 8000 and SMTP port 587. Therefore, both server-related functions and the SMTP service of host port 8000 connected to Nginx must be open.
2. Ports (8000->80) entering Nginx from Django must be assigned internal server port 8000 and SMTP port 587, respectively. There are two external connections (Django-Nginx-host), which should handle 8000 and 587 respectively, and the host port responsible for 587 should have SMTP service open.
   Can you tell me which one is the right way?

Comment: I suspect that it is the smtp server refusing the connection, your configuration looks OK. I would try to make a simple python script that sends an email from the same server where you are hosting your dockers and see what happens.

Comment: AFAIR EMAIL_PORT should be int, not str. Could you try EMAIL_PORT = 587? I don't have port 587 exposed, and gmail SMTP is working fine.

Comment: @Marco It looks like I didn't link Django(587) to Nginx in a docker container. So I tried to connect Django 587 with Nginx (for SMTP), but couldn't send an email.
But your answer maybe implies that hosting port 587 is not open. Is my understanding correct? My guess is port 587 works inside docker, I don't know why I need to test the host port.

Comment: @SUTerliakov I tried it, but the mail could not be sent. It could have been a variable type problem, but perhaps something else is a bigger cause.

Comment: Did you solve this at the end? I am facing a similar issue and any hint would be appreciated. Thank you in advance and regards